# Variable in output html

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm customizing a plugin on wordpress and I want to display a GET variable on the html output? How can I do it?

```
$mlpoutputhtml .= "Selected category: "; + the get variable
```

Thanks

Comment: echo $_GET['your_variable];

Comment: This, `$mlpoutputhtml .= "Selected category: " . $_GET['your_variable'];` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['thename'];
```

read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

This,

```
$mlpoutputhtml .= "Selected category: " . $_GET['your_variable'];
```

Comment: @RajdeepPaul - Can you convert your comment to an answer, and Quentin can you remove this answer, and wait until Rajdeep has provided his, so you can properly mark it as accepted?